# How to configure Web Application to accept connections from reverse proxy only

Tags: http, nginx, proxy, webserver, lighttpd

The reverse proxy is authenticating users and distributing requests to other apps. How can I make sure that application will receive no connections other that those coming from the reverse proxy ?
Firewall will not help with the traffic coming from the local machine.

Comment: Male them listen to localhost only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a header in the HTTP request incoming when it passes in your reverse proxy. Then in you application, you could check if that key/value is present and at that format you decided.

Simple but enough for what you describe.